# Node.js: How to find out contents of a 400 bad request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-status-code-400, server-response

I'm building a server with Node.js. For several reasons, I can't fire valid requests from client side (using an app or Postman). But I can log out data on the server side. Currently, one route is buggy and returns "Error 400: bad request"s. How can I find out the reason?

Here is my route (it uses [Now Serverless functions](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/serverless-functions/introduction/)):

```js
const route = ({ request, response }) => {
  if (!response.headersSent) {
    response.locals
      .dispatch(postIssueToken(request.body))
      .then(body => response.status(201).send(body))
      .catch(err => handleError(response, err));
  }
  console.log('response', response);
  console.log('response.body', response.body);
  return { request, response };
};
```

I tried logging out the response, but there are hundreds of keys on it and I can't find the `content`. For example `response.body` is `undefined`.

How can I find out the reason of the 400 error? I assume there must be a message or something attached to the response somewhere?

For completion, here is the full response:

```
response ServerResponse {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    finish: [ [Function: bound resOnFinish], [Function], [AsyncFunction] ]
  },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  outputData: [],
  outputSize: 0,
  writable: true,
  _last: true,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: false,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
  sendDate: true,
  _removedConnection: false,
  _removedContLen: false,
  _removedTE: false,
  _contentLength: 171,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: true,
  _headerSent: true,
  socket: Socket {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: null,
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: null,
      pipesCount: 0,
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: true,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: true,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      paused: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrain: 0,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null
    },
    readable: true,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [Array],
      timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
      data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
      error: [Function: socketOnError],
      close: [Array],
      drain: [Function: bound socketOnDrain],
      resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
      pause: [Function: onSocketPause]
    },
    _eventsCount: 8,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: false,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      bufferedRequest: null,
      lastBufferedRequest: null,
      pendingcb: 3,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      bufferedRequestCount: 0,
      corkedRequestsFree: [Object]
    },
    writable: true,
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: Server {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      headersTimeout: 40000,
      _connectionKey: '4:127.0.0.1:0',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11
    },
    _server: Server {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      headersTimeout: 40000,
      _connectionKey: '4:127.0.0.1:0',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11
    },
    parser: HTTPParser {
      '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
      '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
      '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
      '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
      '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
      _headers: [],
      _url: '',
      socket: [Circular],
      incoming: [IncomingMessage],
      outgoing: null,
      maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
      _consumed: true,
      onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming],
      parsingHeadersStart: 0
    },
    on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    _paused: false,
    _httpMessage: [Circular],
    [Symbol(asyncId)]: 110,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: TCP {
      reading: true,
      onconnection: null,
      _consumed: true,
      [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular]
    },
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
  },
  connection: Socket {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: null,
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: null,
      pipesCount: 0,
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: true,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: true,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      paused: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrain: 0,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null
    },
    readable: true,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [Array],
      timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
      data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
      error: [Function: socketOnError],
      close: [Array],
      drain: [Function: bound socketOnDrain],
      resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
      pause: [Function: onSocketPause]
    },
    _eventsCount: 8,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: false,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      bufferedRequest: null,
      lastBufferedRequest: null,
      pendingcb: 3,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      bufferedRequestCount: 0,
      corkedRequestsFree: [Object]
    },
    writable: true,
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: Server {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      headersTimeout: 40000,
      _connectionKey: '4:127.0.0.1:0',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11
    },
    _server: Server {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      headersTimeout: 40000,
      _connectionKey: '4:127.0.0.1:0',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11
    },
    parser: HTTPParser {
      '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
      '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
      '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
      '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
      '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
      _headers: [],
      _url: '',
      socket: [Circular],
      incoming: [IncomingMessage],
      outgoing: null,
      maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
      _consumed: true,
      onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming],
      parsingHeadersStart: 0
    },
    on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    _paused: false,
    _httpMessage: [Circular],
    [Symbol(asyncId)]: 110,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: TCP {
      reading: true,
      onconnection: null,
      _consumed: true,
      [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular]
    },
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
  },
  _header: 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n' +
    'content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n' +
    'content-length: 171\r\n' +
    'etag: W/"ab-khiRb+G+3bll2jfE5KBPWTiybSE"\r\n' +
    'Date: Fri, 22 Nov 2019 09:58:51 GMT\r\n' +
    'Connection: close\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
  _sent100: false,
  _expect_continue: false,
  status: [Function],
  send: [Function],
  json: [Function],
  locals: {
    get: [Function: get],
    db: {
      admin: [FirebaseNamespace],
      database: [Database],
      firestore: [Firestore],
      app: [FirebaseApp]
    },
    dispatch: [AsyncFunction]
  },
  statusCode: 400,
  statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
  [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
  [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
  [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
    'content-type': [ 'content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8' ],
    'content-length': [ 'content-length', 171 ],
    etag: [ 'etag', 'W/"ab-khiRb+G+3bll2jfE5KBPWTiybSE"' ]
  }
}
```

Comment: the server isn't sending any more information than `400 - Bad request` - so your client has no possible way of knowing why you get that request ... having said that, this error is defined as `400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).` - does that help?

Comment: @Bravo Thank you. Usually the server responds with a message which parameter was malformed. E.g. if a required parameter is missing it responds with status code 400 and `"issuer is required."`.
So are you sure the server isn't giving back any response body?

Comment: you know where you `console.log('response.body', response.body)` ... that's a response *you* are sending ... so if there's no information in it, it's because you haven't put it there - and the code in `response.locals.dispatch` has nothing to do with the response you are sending because it hasn't run yet by the time you are outputtng that console.log